# How can I query with elemMatch in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to query a user in my mongodb collection based on the following mongodb query:

`db.users.find("boxes":{"$elemMatch":{"a":"foo","b":"bar"}})`

This works if I query directly with mongodb. It returns any user that has a box with a="foo" and b="bar".

How can I query this in mongoosejs? I've tried using `User.find().elemMatch` but it doesn't work. That seems like its just projecting the results anyway. The original mongodb query does work for me though, I just need to be able to replicate it in mongoosejs. Any ideas?

Comment: Does using that exact same `"boxes":{"$elemMatch":{"a":"foo","b":"bar"}}` not work in the mongoose `.find` method?

Comment: @TimBrown, nope, it returns nothing when I do that

Comment: That exact query will work with Mongoose, so something else is going on here.  What does your Mongoose query code look like?

Comment: @JohnnyHK, I just setup mongoose debug to tell me what it's generating for queries. It's calling this on the native driver. `db.users.find("boxes":{"$elemMatch":{"a":"foo","b":"bar"}})` which is exactly the query that works when I query it without mongoose. Looks like you're right something else is going on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Documentation for elemMatch in mongoose is [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-elemMatch).
I've not tested it, but it looks like you'll want to do

`User.find().elemMatch("boxes", {"a":"foo","b":"bar"})`

Comment: I tried that. It didn't return anything. I went through the mongoose and mongodb docs for a while by the way. I thought User.find().elemMatch would work also. it just returns an empty array.

Comment: Just to make sure of the basics, you're getting the results by calling `.exec(CALLBACK_WITH_DATA_HERE)`, and not using the actual return of , `.elemMatch`, correct?

Comment: elemMatch returns a query, but yes I am using the callback in exec `User.find().elemMatch...exec(function(err, results){})`

Comment: this answers the question as I asked it, there were some other issues with how I handled the query that caused it to break so I assumed I was using the query promise api wrong. Turns out the way Tim explained it here is the way I was using it to begin with and it's right. Thanks for the help tim. For the record, if you know how to use the native api, the native queries work straight in the User.find/findOne/etc methods

Answer (score 7):

Tim's answer is correct, but if anyone runs into confusion with what mongoose generates for queries on the mongo native API, I used this to figure that out

```
mongoose.set('debug', function (coll, method, query, doc) {
    console.log(coll + " " + method + " " + JSON.stringify(query) + " " + JSON.stringify(doc));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the proper way to use $elemMatch. I can't test your exact query because I don't have your schema. But there are a few ways:

```
let users = await User.find({
        pet_names: { 
            $elemMatch: { 
                $eq: 'Rex'
            }
        }
    });
```

But in your case, it looks like you're trying to query a property of an array element. You can also do:

```
db.users.find({ "boxes.a": "foo", "boxes.b": "bar"});
```

Comment: I think your alternative solution will return a document where any boxes entry has an a:foo, and another entry has b:bar. OP probably is looking for a document that has a box where both properties are set accordingly for the same box.

Comment: This is not an "or" condition. This structure is "and". We use it quite a bit.